# Expandable с помощью RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, recyclerview

Всегда делал скрытие под-списков с помощью ExpandableListView.

*Можно ли стандартными средствами сделать аналогичное в RecyclerView ?* Или лучше использовать старый-добрый ListView?

**Если можно, то как ?**

Comment: Можно, но такого класса пока нет, придется ручками всё ваять. Есть библиотеки, которые добавляют класс абсолютно по аналогии, как и ExpandableListView. Работают отлично, вот что я нашел сразу https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/expand-a-recyclerview-in-four-steps/ там же ссылка на gitHub

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, а как вы думаете, не лучше использовать проверенный ExpandableListView?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, или все таки  RecyclerView имеет преимущества перед   ListView ?

Comment: Лично мое мнение, я бы использовал библиотеку те RecyclerView. Я использовал её один раз, но отработала очень стабильно. Мне понравилось, и ещё... я подгружал довольно сложный контент с анимацией в моем случае там list вообще был не уместен.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, а в ListView можно реализовать, например перетаскивание элементов ? Или такое возможно в RecyclerView  ?